# How to send "frozen" SPL-token (NFT)?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft

How can I send tokens (NFT) if the token account has `state - frozen` ? Is there any way to do it with `TransferInstruction` ?

Cause they just don't go through in a transaction from one token account to a second token account. Is there any way to unfreeze them?